# ROW_NUMBER - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

This is my table schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTBL](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Score] [INT] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OP_ProspectTBL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO MYTBL VALUES ('a', GETUTCDATE(), 1, GETUTCDATE());
INSERT INTO MYTBL VALUES ('O', GETUTCDATE(), 112, GETUTCDATE());
INSERT INTO MYTBL VALUES ('Ob', GETUTCDATE(), 12, GETUTCDATE());
select * from MYTBL;
```

Query

```sql
DECLARE @IN_ORDERBY_COL int = 3, 
        @IN_ORDERBY_DIRECTION int  = 1, 
        @IN_PAGENEXT int = 50, 
        @IN_PAGESKIP int = 0;

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
                    (CASE WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_DIRECTION = 1 THEN
                        (
                            CASE 
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 1 THEN P.CreatedDate
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 2 THEN P.LastModifiedDate
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 3 THEN P.Designation
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 4 THEN P.Score
                            END
                        ) 
                    END) ASC,
                    (CASE WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_DIRECTION = 2 THEN
                        (
                            CASE 
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 1 THEN P.CreatedDate
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 2 THEN P.LastModifiedDate
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 3 THEN P.Designation
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 4 THEN P.Score
                            END
                        ) 
                    END) DESC
                ) AS [row_num],
COUNT(*) OVER () AS [total_rows],
*
FROM [dbo].[MYTBL] P WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY row_num OFFSET @IN_PAGESKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @IN_PAGENEXT ROWS ONLY;
```

The query above is a stored procedure, I'm trying to sort based on Column.

The problem is of the all columns in Sort (2 are of `DATETIME` type and other one is `NVARCHAR(10)`)

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1067d0a10dfea5655f0b611f1f47372c)

When I'm trying to order by Company, I'm getting below error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I'm not able to find any matching question which solves my question, if you find any kindly answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, convert the date to string:

```
DECLARE @IN_ORDERBY_COL int = 3, 
        @IN_ORDERBY_DIRECTION int  = 1, 
        @IN_PAGENEXT int = 50, 
        @IN_PAGESKIP int = 0;

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
                    (CASE WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_DIRECTION = 1 THEN
                        (
                            CASE 
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 1 THEN CONVErT(VARCHAR(32), P.CreatedDate, 121)
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 2 THEN CONVErT(VARCHAR(32),P.LastModifiedDate, 121)
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 3 THEN P.Designation
                            END
                        ) 
                    END) ASC,
                    (CASE WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_DIRECTION = 2 THEN
                        (
                            CASE 
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 1 THEN CONVErT(VARCHAR(32),P.CreatedDate, 121)
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 2 THEN CONVErT(VARCHAR(32),P.LastModifiedDate, 121)
                                WHEN @IN_ORDERBY_COL = 3 THEN P.Designation
                            END
                        ) 
                    END) DESC
                ) AS [row_num],
COUNT(*) OVER () AS [total_rows],
*
FROM [dbo].[MYTBL] P WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY row_num OFFSET @IN_PAGESKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @IN_PAGENEXT ROWS ONLY
```

;

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you please suggest a better way to convert/cast if we have `INT` datatype as well? [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e95474ed87ef694137eda66b8e25d422)

Comment: Again, convert to string. The issue the numbers stored as text are not sorted correctly. Because of this, you can do something like this `SELECT CAST(1000000000000 + 1 AS VARCHAR(32))` - the idea is to pad the number with `1` and `zeros` and get property string sort ;)

Answer (score 1):

This occurs due to data type precedence in SQL server. If you check this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15%20if%20you) you can see that

> When an operator combines expressions of different data types, the data type with the lower precedence is first converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion isn't a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned.

So there are two ways you can handle this. Either like @gotqn mentioned in his answer or you have to take the case statement out of the row_number which will be a long code. I do believe even though this is an easy way of doing things, this seems to be a wrong approach.

Comment: Could you please reference any article, which has other way to sort based on various types of columns.